# WPF привязка int из Window.Resources

Tags: wpf, binding

нужно чтобы высота и ширина окна и Window.Clip RectangleGeometry Rect брались из ресурсов

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="windowW">120</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="windowH">80</sys:Int32>

    </Window.Resources>
    // тут нормально
    <Window.Height>
        <Binding Mode="OneWay" Source="{StaticResource windowH}"/>
    </Window.Height>
    <Window.Width>
        <Binding Mode="OneWay" Source="{StaticResource windowW}"/>
    </Window.Width>

<Window.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry>
            <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                <Rect X="0" 
                      Y="0"
                      Width="...."/> // тут ненормально
            </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
        </RectangleGeometry>
    </Window.Clip>
```

Comment: А зачем вы так сложно привязку указываете? Достаточно ведь  `<Window ... Width="{StaticResource windowW}" >` и все, не? Кстати, советую ресурс ы называть полноценно и через точку `Window.Width`, понятней ведь)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ окно с круглыми углами, чтобы при изменении его размеров Window.Clip тоже соот-но  менялся. или есть другой способ?

Comment: Хорошо, что сказали про то, ч о вам надо, только как это отвечает на поставленный мною вопрос? Зачем вы открываете каждое свойство, где создаёте объект binding, если сразу можно (и нужно) указать привязку? Касательно вашей задачи, это делается по другому, без привязок к размерам окна. Достаточно переопределить шаблон, где будет основным объектом простой border с закруглением. Ну а так, нынче Windows 11 сама все закругляет, может оставить это на неё?